# npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'path/package.json' with YML-file

Tags: node.js, gitlab-ci

I'm trying to use gitlab CI/CD and make a yml-file that will run all tests in the frontend. The problem is I get the error

`npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '{path}\{branch}\package.json`

Which makes sense, because the package.json is not in `{branch}` (the branch), but in `{branch}/myreactapp`. So the path should have been `{branch}/myreactapp/package.json`. How do I solve this?

yml-file:

```
stages: ["test", "deploy"]

test:
    stage: test
    script: npm run test

deploy:
    stage: deploy
    script: npm run deploy
```

[image]

I already tried `before_script: - npm install` and `before_script: - npm init` and also both combined.

Reproducing: I made a react.js project in my branch and added a `test.test.js` file and put a test in there that always passes.

```
it('works ', () => {});
```

And than I just tried to run the pipeline. Also changed (`jest` was `react-scripts test`) in `package.json-file`

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "jest",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
```

Comment: Could you share your `.gitlab-ci.yml` ?  Or enable me to reproduce your problem?